# Unmapped target property warning when property name starts with "set"

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm trying to implement a mapping between an entity and DTO using MapStruct. One of the properties to be mapped is "settlementDate". It has the same name in DTO class and the mapping works, but I get the following warning during the compilation:

```
/path/to/project/SomeDataMapper.java:15: warning: Unmapped target property: "tlementDate".
    SomeData toEntity(SomeDataDTO someDataDTO);
```

Is there any way to make MapStruct deal with such a weirdly named property without warnings?

I've tried using `@Mapping` annotation to specify the names explicitly, but this didn't help:

```
@Mapping(target = "settlementDate", source = "settlementDate")
SomeData toEntity(SomeDataDTO someDataDTO);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that this is a bug, the name is not that weird . Can you please create an issue in the bug tracker (if you haven't already)

For the time being you can try and "use" the wrong property mapping. Something like:

```
@Mapping(target = "tlementDate", source = "settlementDate")
SomeData toEntity(SomeDataDTO someDataDTO)
```

Comment: thanks, I wasn't sure this is a bug, so just asked here first. and somebody has already created an issue a couple days ago (https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1799). so I will watch that one.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the name "settlementDate", apparently since the generation it's considered like a setter and not a variable.
So I suggest to you :

```
 @Mapping(target="settlementDate",source="settlementDate", qualifiedByName="methodName")
 SomeData toEntity(SomeDataDTO someDataDTO);

 @Named("methodName")
 default ... methodName2(... settlementDate){
     //your transformation to get settlementDate of SomeData from settlementDate from SomDataDTO
 }
```

I haven't tried with a name beginning with "set", else it's working